# Spark Delta Merge runs too slow in Test

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scalatest, delta-lake

We have a Scalatest + Spark based Test. The Data transformation is fairly complex with lots of transformation and the final step is Delta merge.

The tests have minimal input data (around 20 KB) and produce a small Delta table (.parquet is around 10 KB)
On profiling, it was found that the below code take around 90% of the total time execution (around 3 minutes).
Note that the Delta table was empty before the merge.

```
deltaTable.as("existing")
            .merge(dfNewData.as("new"), "new.GUID = existing.GUID and new.RSid = existing.RSid")
            .whenMatched("existing.GUID <> 'U'")
            .update(Map("Id1" -> col("new.Id1"),... => around 20 columns
            ))
            .whenMatched("existing.GUID = 'U' and new.Id1 = existing.Id1")
            .delete()
            .whenNotMatched()
            .insertAll()
            .execute()
```

The time taken is almost identical in Windows Intellij Setup and also in Azure DevOps CI.

Any idea why it is talking such a long time for such small amount of data and how can it be improved?

Comment: can you add the delta version used?

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
            <artifactId>delta-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: You should look to upgrading to a later version, they introduce deletion vectors etc. to improve perf when you actually have data...
How long does it take if, instead of merging, you simply write.format("delta") the contents out?

Comment: From 3 minutes to 1.5 minutes! Another observation is, if I comment out update and delete commands in the above deltaMerge call, time reduced to 1.5 mins. The funny thing is, the delta table is originally empty. So there is nothing to update and delete, still it takes so long time..

Comment: On inpecting the Spark log : 15:01:02 INFO WorkflowEventsTransformation: Perf : deltaMerge 1
23/09/22 15:02:06 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: $anonfun$recordDeltaOperationInternal$1 at DatabricksLogging.scala:77
23/09/22 15:02:06 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 32 ($anonfun$recordDeltaOperationInternal$1 at DatabricksLogging.scala:77) with 50 output partitions. I don't know what is this 1 minute at the beginning gone for.

Comment: Tried with delta version 2.4.0, still no change in performance.

Comment: not surprised re 2.4 hence writing "when you actually have data".  Does "existing" actually have a transaction log yet?  (e.g. add a row, then delete it).  Merging is not "fast"  but a doubling of time is odd for something which can only end in an insert.

Comment: That it's taking 1.5 minutes to write out such tiny amounts of data is odd and points to evaluating it being slower.  Can you try to cache "dfNewData" before merging with it?  It may be, as merge runs two actions, that it's simply being evaluated twice.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, it takes 3m to do the merge, and 1.5m to do a simple insert/append.

If the dfNewData involves joins, calculations etc. you may incur two runs of the dfNewData plan, caching should reduce that.  Note caching *can* be more expensive than writing to a temporary location and using that to read from.

Please attempt:

```scala
val cached = dfNewData.cache

deltaTable.as("existing")
            .merge(cached.as("new"), "new.GUID = existing.GUID and new.RSid = existing.RSid")
            .whenMatched("existing.GUID <> 'U'")
            .update(Map("Id1" -> col("new.Id1"),... => around 20 columns
            ))
            .whenMatched("existing.GUID = 'U' and new.Id1 = existing.Id1")
            .delete()
            .whenNotMatched()
            .insertAll()
            .execute()
```

Comment: The current working solution is to split the delete and remaining upsert to to calls and write the intermediate DF to a temp table. A very strange problem with delta merge - after the execution of delta merge call, the content of original dfNewData gets altered (even though this was supposed to be immutable!)!! TO avoid this problem, the only solution was to write a temp delta table and read the content of this persisted dfNew data for the second delta merge (upsert) call.